# How do I display either body or file from content

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, view

I am a new in Drupal. I want your help for doing this please help

I have created one Content type with fields( Title, Body, File) and also added content through this content type. But Some of the content didn't have file filed and some of the content having the only file. In the view, I want to show both either body or file. if suppose file field is empty then it should display the body of the same content.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this by creating a custom node template for particular content type. So if you have a content type 'news', for example, the you can create a node template for this content type and customized the front-end display of the content. See below how it would work.

As per the Drupal [theme suggestions](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/theming/template-theme-hook-suggestions), create a node template, named, `node--news.tpl.php` (copying the existing node.tpl.php file) in your custom (active) theme directory under the `templates` folder. On this template, you will be able to access the `$node` object variable, containing complete node information including fields and data.

Suppose your fields are `field_image` and `body` then replace your template's code `print render($content);` with the following lines:

```
if(!empty($content['body']){
print render($content['body']);
} else {
print render($content['field_image']);
}
```

For more details: https://www.drupal.org/node/1323842
Hope this help!